# Скрыть исходный код скриптов

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте. На карту наносится большое количество меток с банулами. Все эти метки генерируются в процессе загрузки сайта, выполняется куча разных проверок и так далее, что в итоге сейчас объекты заполняются таким образом

```
var geoObjects;
geoObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(<?=$map_items[0];?>);
```

Где $map_items[0] - это сгенерированная в процессе работы сайта json строка. Все работает отлично, но при просмотре исходного кода страницы код становится "грязным" (см. скрин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так много строк далее. Хотелось бы как-то вынести эту инфу в отдельный файл js. Но используется php переменная. Подскажите, как это проще всего реализовать? Может имеется какая-та функция в api карт яндекса для этих целей?

Думал при загрузке страницы каждый раз создавать json файл и подгружать его в метод geoQuery. Скопировал текущий код, а он в файле весит 2.5 МБ, каждый раз генерить и считывать его скорее всего большая нагрузка на сервер? Или все же не страшены эти строки в исходном коде и просто следует забить?

Answer (score 1):

Выводить 2мб данные в браузер клиентами точно не стоит. Ни в отдельном файле, ни в основном.

В API карт есть модуль для показа больших объектов данных
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/about-docpage/

Для работы требуется сервер, который будет получать на вход номера тайлов и возвращать объекты, который находятся в этих тайлах.